# How to use annotate to group by in Django?

Tags: sql, database, django, django-queryset

Suppose I have a Django model...

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

and I want to know how many publishers each author has used? I've tried something like...

```
Book.objects.value('author').annotate(Count('publisher'))
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. What is the correct Django query?

Or alternatively how do I convert this sql query into Django?

```
SELECT author, COUNT(publisher) FROM Book GROUP BY author;
```

Comment: this kind of query works for me... You have typo here: Book.objects.value('author').annotate(Count('publisher')) - need to be values not value